# SMO C# alter fail on EXISTING stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I am trying to programatically change a stored procedure with SMO in C#. Everything seems to work apart from the alter step. connection and stored procedure connect are fine. Please help, why is it not changing my database?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

namespace DBChecker
{
    public class A
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String sqlServerLogin = "*****";
            String password = "****";
            String instanceName = "";
            String remoteSvrName = "****";


            ServerConnection srvConn2 = new ServerConnection(remoteSvrName);
            srvConn2.LoginSecure = true;
            Server srv3 = new Server(srvConn2);
            Console.WriteLine(srv3.Information.Version);  
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Established");

            Database db;
            db = srv3.Databases["decision"];
            Console.WriteLine("DB Connection Established");

            StoredProcedure sp;
            sp = new StoredProcedure(db,"copy_alias_by_type");
            Console.WriteLine("SP Connection Established");

            sp.TextMode = false;
            sp.AnsiNullsStatus = false;
            sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = false;

            StoredProcedureParameter param;
            param = new StoredProcedureParameter(sp, "@alstyp");

            param.DataType = DataType.Char(100);
            sp.Refresh();
            sp.Alter();

            Console.WriteLine("DataType Changed");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your change is not getting applied is that although you created the `param` StoredProcedureParameter with a reference to the `sp` StoredProcedure, you never actually added as a parameter for the stored procedure. (Don't worry, I also had a "hu?" moment when I saw/realized it).

Change your code snippet to look like this snippet:

```
StoredProcedureParameter param;
param = new StoredProcedureParameter(sp, "@alstyp");
sp.Parameters.Add(param);  // Add the parameter as a parameter to the StoredProcedure
```

This will then make that when you call `sp.Alter()`, it actually applies the code.

Reference: [MSDN: Creating, Altering, and Removing Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162190.aspx)